# KMS, linux kernel 3.7 and ati mobility radeon x1350

Tags: linux, arch-linux, kernel, kernel-module

I got problem with booting new kernel. If I on bootloader pass nomodeset flag to the kernel linux boots up successfully but it doesnt load radeon module to kernel which is really frustrating cause I cannot work on fallbacked vessa drivers(screen is flickering to much and its iritating). By cannot boot I mean it just hangs on udev undefinatly. If I pass nomodeset to the kernel while booting then I have my vessa drivers which I can't really use for anything meangfull.. :/

Any suggestion is appriciated.

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, then enter:

```
sudo modprobe -r radeon
sudo modprobe -r drm
sudo modprobe radeon modeset=1
```